# ViewPager image view show null at random item position in recycler View

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager

I have a recycler view which contains the view pager for the image gallery. My list view showing all data but at random item position view pager for the image is blank

```
 @Override
public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, final int position) {
    LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    assert mLayoutInflater != null;
    View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_pager, container, false);

    ImageView imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_pager);
    final TextView more_photos_text = itemView.findViewById(R.id.more_photos_text);
    final RelativeLayout more_photos = itemView.findViewById(R.id.more_photos);
    more_photos.setTag(position);

    if (position == image.size( ) - 1) {
        if (screen == Command.ABS  && !isShowFullGallery) {
            more_photos.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            more_photos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            more_photos_text.setText(Html.fromHtml("<u>For more photos</u>"));
        }
    }
    Log.e("image-----", galleryImages.get(position));
    Engine.getInstance(mContext).loadImage(mContext, galleryImages.get(position), imageView, Constant.PriorityOption.IMMEDIATE);
    container.addView(itemView,0);

    more_photos.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        callGallery(0);


    });

    imageView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        callGallery(position);


    });

    return itemView;
}
```

Comment: Can you please share your code here.

Comment: Keep in mind that the recycler view will recycle cells, so you will have to re-instantiate each item every time `onBindViewHolder` is called with all data to display the images.

Comment: I have already done this in onBindViewHolder but this issue is very random

Comment: @VijayKharwar can you set `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(20);` for each ViewPager and see if the problem persists? It's not a final solution, but you can see if it's the ViewPager or RecyclerView that is causing the problem.